# jquery populate input text fields based on datepicker

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is create a form which will allow users to enter in a form the number of hours they've worked over a two week period.

The form has 14 rows containing fields asking for start and end time. This I can do.

What I need to do is in the form is: the user selects a weekending date, which then populates 14 text fields with a date based on the previous 14 dates.

Now I know I can use the following script to do one date, but how do I do multiple fields at once without so many lines of code.

Sample :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
        var date2 = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+3)
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker("setDate", date2);
    }
});
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});

</head>
<body>
<p>Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
<p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set 14 dates, you can use `each()` to loop thru the `datepicker`s if each `datepicker` have different values. Example below.

If all 14 `datepicker`s have the same values. You can use the class as a selector to assign the value. like `$( ".datepicker-to-fill" ).datepicker("setDate",date2);`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  onClose: function() {
           $( ".datepicker-to-fill" ).each(function(){
             var days = parseInt( $(this).data("days") );
             var date2 = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
             date2.setDate( date2.getDate() + days ); 
             $( this ).datepicker("setDate",date2);
           });
  }
 });
 $( ".datepicker-to-fill" ).datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Main Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


<p>Date1: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="1" id="datepicker1"></p> 
<p>Date2: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="2" id="datepicker2"></p> 
<p>Date3: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="3" id="datepicker3"></p> 
<p>Date4: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="4" id="datepicker4"></p> 
<p>Date5: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="5" id="datepicker5"></p> 
<p>Date6: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="6" id="datepicker6"></p> 
<p>Date7: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="7" id="datepicker7"></p> 
<p>Date8: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="8" id="datepicker8"></p> 
<p>Date9: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="9" id="datepicker9"></p> 
<p>Date10: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="10" id="datepicker10"></p> 
<p>Date11: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="11" id="datepicker11"></p> 
<p>Date12: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="12" id="datepicker12"></p> 
<p>Date13: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="13" id="datepicker13"></p> 
<p>Date14: <input type="text" class="datepicker-to-fill" data-days="14" id="datepicker14"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie, this is perfect for my needs and saved heaps of time.